# Event Hub Error: Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: ExpiredToken

Tags: c#, azure

I am working on program in which sending messages from C# console application to Azure Event Hub. Code reference link as follows:

Ref Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send

In this above code i am getting exception as: Put token failed. Status Code: 401 : Expired Token. I have tried to regenerate primary and secondary key. Below is the format of connection string and entity path values as follows:

[image]

Please provide solution for it. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

I hope it is not too late!

I had the same issue and my problem was, that I have changed the system time from the device, that connects to the event hub. I have set it from 7 o'clock to 4 o'clock.

Comment: I know this is my problem.  I've had it before, but it seems to stick.  I need to refresh the token somehow.

Comment: This solved my problems! Booted into Linux in the morning which apparently changed the system time.

Answer (score 3):

The following may be a very specific scenario.

If you are facing this issue running your app with Docker in Windows and Docker is running via WSL 2 (instead of HyperV), there is a WSL 2 issue that still needs to be addressed by Microsoft:

It is a time synchronization issue between the host OS and the running containers. They basically have a different date/time and that creates trouble when authenticating via tokens that expire.

This happened when my laptop woke up after sleep/hibernation. I run my app using Docker containers. When it tries to connect to Service Bus I start to get those unauthorized errors, but only after sleep mode, not before.

Some said it got solved by restarting the docker host. In my case it only worked restarting my PC. After a while I found:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245

Now I don't need to reboot Windows anymore, just running

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Fixes the issue forcing a time sync between OS/containers (it will also cause a docker host restart).

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same when running inside docker for windows. I restarted the docker host and it worked - no clue why

Comment: Same problem, using WSL2, had to reboot Windows - Docker restart didn't fix the date/time inside the container

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue "Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: Unauthorized" was caused by the networking configuration of the storage account where Azure EventHub client persists checkpoints. Both the SA and EH have had whitelisted client address, and it works when I run client app from my laptop (behind the proxy btw). But when the same client deployed to AKS and acting through AKS egress public IP, even this IP whitelisted on the SA and EH, the EH accepts incoming connection, but the SA decline it. I am not sure where the AKS pod inciating connection from_ no any logged connection attempts on the SA. When I made SA accept connections from "All networks", the issue "Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: Unauthorized" has gone. Microsoft reccomended to deploy SA into another region to have EH and SA in different regions, but I didn´t test it yet, and due to billed traffic I wouldn´t.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

it happens when the local time in your docker container is different, to fix the issue please check the date in the docker container as

1.docker exec -it  /bin/sh
2.#date
If you see the UTC time in docker and the corresponding time in local machine are not matching then you need to run a new copy of the container as follows

Command
docker run -d -p  -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro 
The command will syn docker container time with local machine.

For example
docker run -d -p 53238:80 -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro aba.azurecr.io/busbasedsolutions:v1

I have put complete name of a docker image but you can have your own versions.